# Finder window opens scrolled down

Tags: finder, external-disk, macos

Nothing serious but a bit irritating :)

A removable USB storage, formatted as FAT32 (actually this is an Android tablet but it doesn't seem to matter), is used on several Macs, all running the same OS (Mavericks) at the same patch level.

On one of the Macs, and only that one, when the media is inserted and the FS mounted, the first opened window (the top of the file hierearchy), displayed as a list, start to be displayed wedged at the bottom of the list (as if the window has been fully scrolled down). On all the other Macs it opens wedged at the top.

Other removable medias don't exhibit that behaviour on the "different" Mac (they start listed from the begin, at the top, the opening window is not scrolled down).

Why? How?
How can we get rid of that?

All this has been ineffective:
- The window has been thoroughly scrolled up before ejecting the media.
- Changing and reverting the order and/or the sorting of the file list in the window before ejecting has no effect, switching to icon or column view and reverting is no more successful.
- The file hierarchy of the media has been cleaned (._* files, .Trashes/, .fseventsd/, etc. have been wiped).
The Finder Preferences seem to be the same across all the Macs.

Any trick or hint where this may be tweacked, cached, sticked?
On the Media? on "the" Mac? buried in the filesystem or in the preferences?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Mac showing the problem

- edit `com.apple.finder.plist` in `~/Library/Preferences`
- set to 0 or remove scrollPositionY (and scroolPositionX) for the list view
- save that preference file
- restart the finder (option click in the dock).

Comment: Please edit your question directly with new information about the problem (and use the contact form linked at the bottom to have your two accounts merged).

Comment: Also, how does one edit a Apple binary property list?

Answer (score 0):

This by and large happens in light of the fact that you have the Finder see recorded by date adjusted or a comparative criteria that can be powerfully overhauled. In these cases, regardless of the possibility that you have not balanced the record, a foundation errand or other program may do as such, and this overhaul could bring about the document vanishing from view. On the off chance that the record is chosen, then your view may take after the document to its new area in the rundown.