# How to disable the scroll position saving in Finder?

Tags: finder, high-sierra, macos

By default, the Finder always saves the last scroll position in folders and restores it when these folders are opened again later.

How can I disable this feature? I want all folders to always open in the Finder scrolled from the beginning. High Sierra is installed.

Comment: This is not only a problem in 10.13 but also 10.12. Finder keeps remembering an horizontal scroll offset, which is really annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/258275/279245). In summary:

1. Open `com.apple.finder.plist` in `~/Library/Preferences` (Check [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254938/how-to-open-plist-files-in-macos-sierra-without-using-xcode) if you don't know how to edit this file)
2. Locate **StandardViewSettings > ListViewSetting** and set `scrollPositionY` (or `scrollPositionX`) set to 0. (Note, there are other setting where the scroll position pops up so it depends a little bit where you experience the problem)
3. Save that preference
4. Restart the finder: hold down the option key and do a right-click on the Finder's icon in the dock and choose *Relaunch*.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not help. I have all the «scrollPositionY» values in «.plist» file already equal to zero — obviously, this setting only affects the Finder scrolling position by default, when a particular folder has never been opened.